# Saving files is not enabled in hosted mode. Please inspect using chrome://inspect

Tags: google-chrome, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-native-app, har

Testing Samsung TV, and am trying to save the data as HAR in Tizen web developr tool, however, receiving an error message when trying. What may I need to change in the settings (?) to enable saving files?

```
Saving files is not enabled in hosted mode. Please inspect using chrome://inspect
```

Comment: How are you trying to save this data (what is your code or what button are you clicking)? What is the Tizen web developer tool (do you mean Chrome DevTools)? Where and when does this error message appear?